# LOOKUP reference with mulitple outcome values

Tags: microsoft-excel, lookup

I am looking to pull out and display the multiple ages of people associated with a single reference number.

Below snipped displays the sheet set up. The sheet has approximate 2500 rows:

```
App ref,Relationship,Age,Date of Birth,Gender,Marital Status
1,A1,34,12-Apr-85,F,SINGLE
1,A1,34,12-Apr-85,F,SINGLE
1,PT,30,12-Oct-89,M,SINGLE
830,A1,63,10-Nov-56,F,MARRIED
830,SN,32,11-Nov-87,M,SINGLE
830,HU,65,24-Sep-54,M,MARRIED
846,A1,75,11-Aug-44,M,MARRIED
846,A2,72,16-Nov-47,F,MARRIED
```

For each `App Ref`, I want to pull out all associated ages:

```
| App ref | Age 1 | Age 2 | Age 3 |
|---------|-------|-------|-------|
| 1       |  34   |  34   |  30   |
| 830     |  63   |  32   |  65   |
| 846     |  75   |  72   |  -    |
```

Comment: how many different ages could there be ? is it always 3 as per example ?

Comment: Hi Ross and welcome to Superuser. Help us help you: don't post your example data from a spreadsheet as an image. I can't copy paste that into me Excel and create a solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy column A to an unused column where your target data will start and use Data, Remove Duplicates to generate a set of unique *App ref* numbers. In my sample image below, I've used column H.
2. Put this formula in the row 1 cell immediately to the right of your unique *App ref* numbers and drag it right. In my sample, I've started in I1.

   ```
   =TEXT(COLUMN(A:A), "\A\g\e 0")
   ```
3. Put this formula under *Age 1* and drag right and down. In my sample, I've started in I2.

   ```
   =IFERROR(INDEX($C:$C, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW($C$2:INDEX($C:$C, MATCH(1E+99, $C:$C)))/($A$2:INDEX($A:$A, MATCH(1E+99, $C:$C))=$H2), COLUMN(A:A))), "")
   ```

[image]

If the *App ref* column is sorted ascending then you can reduce calculation by limiting the lookup rows.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C:$C, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW(INDEX($A:$A, MATCH($H2, $A:$A, 0)):INDEX($A:$A, MATCH($H2, $A:$A))), COLUMN(A:A))), "")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with `Power Query` *a free add-in from Microsoft in Excel 2010+; included as `Get & Transform` in Excel 2016+*

Except for entering the custom column formula, everything can be done from the GUI, and if your original data changes, the query is easily refreshed.

- Select  a cell in your original table
- `Data--> Get & Transform --> from Table/Range`
- Group by `App ref`  *operation == All Rows*

[image]

- Add Custom Column  (to change the `Age` column into a `List`

  - Formula `=Table.Column([Merged],"Age")`
- Right click on the double arrow of this new Custom column and choose to Extract the values using `comma` as the separator
- Split the column using `comma` as the separator.
- Rename the new columns to `Age n` etc
- Close and Load the results

**M-Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"App ref", Int64.Type}, {"Relationship", type text}, {"Age", Int64.Type}, {"Date of Birth", type datetime}, {"Gender", type text}, {"Marital Status", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"App ref"}, {{"Merged", each _, type table [App ref=number, Relationship=text, Age=number, Date of Birth=datetime, Gender=text, Marital Status=text]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each Table.Column([Merged],"Age")),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom", {"Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ","), type text}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Extracted Values", "Custom", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Custom.1", "Custom.2", "Custom.3"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Custom.1", Int64.Type}, {"Custom.2", Int64.Type}, {"Custom.3", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type1",{{"Custom.1", "Age 1"}, {"Custom.2", "Age 2"}, {"Custom.3", "Age 3"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

[image]

[image]